# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method validate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm getting little bit issue in laravel 5.2
When i submit data throgh post. data found in request but not save. pls help.

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3111642/0ec1946875e85f53eaec7970483ff5f0

Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    enter code here

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Customer extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        //$members = Customer::latest()->paginate(10);
        return view('pages.admin.customers.customers', compact('customers'));
        //    ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        return view('pages.admin.customers.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {

        request()->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
        ]);
        Customer::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('customer.index');
    }

}
```

Model file Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname'
        ];
    protected $table = 'customers';
}
```

Comment: Please someone answer me..

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in validation, instead of:

```
request()->validate([
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
        ]);
```

You need use:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required',
]);
```

There are other ways to validate which you can read about in official documentation [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation).